# Can't make a POST request using axios

Tags: axios

The error message I get is

"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5000/user/login. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)."

http-header.js

```
"import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:5000",
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  }
})
```

AuthService.js

```
import axios from '../http-header.js'

export default {
  login : user => {
    return axios.post('/user/login', user)
    .then(res => {
      if(res.status !== 401)
        return res.json().then(data => data)
      else {
        return {isAuthenticated: false, user: {username: "", role: ""}}
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'` to your backend.

Comment: Thanks, I am a newer coder. I wrote this originally using fetch keyword and it worked fine but it broke when I rewrote using axios. Is there a reason why adding this line may not be necessary with fetch but for axios?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it has something to do with the request headers in Axios vs Fetch. ps. You don't need to call `res.json()` with Axios. `return res.json()` to `return res.data` should be enough.

Comment: Cool beans. Thanks again!